# Use C++ Component Object Model in C#

Tags: c#, c++, com

I am trying to build a COM Library in C++, using a C# project for testing. Some methods need to return strings to the caller. On calling these methods from C# I get this: "Access violation reading at location ..."

This is the C++ code from my testproject (apart from all the stuff generated by VS 2010 ATL)

```
//COMTest.idl
[id(1)] HRESULT Test([out,retval] BSTR* ret);

//Program2.h
STDMETHOD(Test)(BSTR* ret);

//Program2.cpp
STDMETHODIMP CProgram2::Test(BSTR* ret)
{
   BSTR tmp = (BSTR)CoTaskMemAlloc(sizeof(wchar_t) * 2);
   tmp[0] = L'H';
   tmp[1] = L'\0';

   *ret = (BSTR)tmp;
   return S_OK;
}
```

In C# I just referenced the DLL from the COM-Tab, turned "Embed Interop Types" off, because it caused errors, and ran this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   COMTestLib.Program2Class instance = new COMTestLib.Program2Class();
   string tmp = instance.Test(); //Where the error occurs

   Console.WriteLine(tmp); //This is not reached

   Console.Read();
}
```

The error occurs after leaving the Test-Method. I debugged the C++ code from within my C# project and the values are placed in the correct locations. I do not get the error if I try to return 0 (gives null in C#), even if I still allocate memory like in the example.

I can not make sense of the address, which the access violation complains about. It is neither the address I am allocating nor any other address used in the method. What also seems weird to me is that the CoTaskMemAlloc-Function always returns addresses with the first byte set to zero (0x00XXXXXX), but that might just be a COM thing.

I ran out of ideas and I cant find much information on this (except for basic COM tutorials) anywhere. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BSTRs require extra memory (to keep track of the string len) so must use [SysAllocString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xda6xzx7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)() function to allocate BSTRs (or use one of the "*smart*" BSTR classes).

So your original code should read like:

```
//Program2.cpp
STDMETHODIMP CProgram2::Test(BSTR* ret)
{
   *ret = SysAllocString(L"H");
   return S_OK;
}
```

A good reading about BSTRs: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/12/52976.aspx

Comment: This works, and since you explained the actual reason for the crash, I made this the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check that your COM project and test project are both STA. Check the bitness too. What if you replace BSTR by LPSTR ?

Comment: Thanks, LPSTR works! I can get on with the project now, but I'd still like to know why BSTR* would not work. Specifying STA for the C# project changed nothing (except for the styling of the errorbox). Both projects are built for x86, if thats what you mean by checking the bitness.

Comment: BSTR appears to be fixed size according to this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ts558h(v=vs.71).aspx. It might not be compatible with C# but I'm not sure. LPSTR is Ansi string.

Comment: I was looking everywhere, but that I did not find. Thanks again, now it works AND it makes sense. :)